# Can I say, 'Before the reader may think I'm mad...'?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Can I say, 'Before the reader may think I'm mad...'?

Let's say I've just written something that might make no sense to most people. Can I use this phrase?

> Before the reader may think I'm mad, I'd like to remind them that my
> previous statement is supported by scientific evidence.

I'm having many doubts about it, especially after running a few searches on ngram and finding virtually no similar examples.

Can I address my reader this way?
Is the phrase even grammatical?
Are there better alternatives?

Comment: In your formal sentence 'mad' may strike the reader as too informal. As for choosing better alternatives, I am afraid it's off-topic on this site.

Comment: mad angry [US] or mad crazy [Brit]? Before the readers finds me unhinged

Comment: 'In case the reader should doubt my sanity...'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for your suggestion. Although I'd like to understand what's wrong with 'before', since you replaced it with 'in case',

Comment: "Before the reader starts to think I'm mad/crazy..."

Comment: I might consider writing this using a phrase along the lines of "Before the reader questions my rationality..." or "...questions my sanity...". However, it would be better to set out your arguments _with references_ **before** drawing the "outrageous" conclusion

Comment: How about: "Before the reader thinks me mad..." That has a similar dated feel, which incidentally suggests the older/Britisher meaning of "mad." I can't definitively say that there's anything wrong with your original formulation, though after reading it a few times, the combination of "before" and "may" (in the sense of "might") strikes me as slightly suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English, we don't usually say someone is "mad." We more often say that someone is "crazy."

You can address the reader as "the reader" and there are many ways to express your thought. For example:

> While the reader might think I'm crazy based on the previous statement....
>
> Before the reader concludes that I'm crazy based on the previous statement....

You can also speak directly to the reader by using "you". For example:

> While you might think I'm crazy for making the previous statement....
>
> Before you jump to the conclusion that I'm crazy based on the previous statement...